# How is the object called from non-instantiated class

Tags: php, object, overloading

on a manual about overloading i couldn't grasp one of the threads. The code is below:

```
<?php

class a
{
   function __get($v)
   {
       $this->$v = new $v;
       return $this->$v;
   }
}

class b
{
    function say($word){
        echo $word;
    }
}
$a = new a();
$a->b->say('hello world');

// echos 'hello world'
?>
```

As it has been pointed in the commented line, it echoes hello world. But even though b hasn't been instantiated how is it being called? Please help, the link to manual is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php), entry is belong to user named **trash80 at gmail dot com**

Comment: As long as `$a->b` is not defined, `$a->__get('b')` is being called. It then instantiates class `b` and returns that instance which then is used to `b::say('hello world')`. Like Neal wrote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What it does:

`$a->b`:

```
function __get('b'){
    $this->b = new b;
    return $this->b;
}
```

`$a->b->say('hello world')`:

```
function say('hello world'){
    echo 'hello world';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is constructed in the __get method of A. Get is a magic method that gets called when you try to retrieve a property, see: [documentation](http://php.net/__get). __get gets passed the property name that is being accessed as a string. Since that string is used to instantiate a class and then return it this works.

The following would work as well:

```
class a
{
   function __get($v)
   {
       $this->$v = new $v;
       return $this->$v;
   }
}

class b
{
    function say($word){
        echo $word;
    }
}

class c
{
    function say($word){
        echo 'c: ' . $word;
    }
}
$a = new a();
$a->b->say('hello world');

// echos 'hello world'

$a->c->say('hello world');

// echos 'c: hello world'
```

Answer (score 3):

but b *has* been instantiated!

Inside class `a`'s magic getter method:

```
function __get($v)
{
    $this->$v = new $v;
    return $this->$v;
}
```

the value of `$v` is 'b' when you call `$a->b` later. This means that the line `$this->$v = new $v;` is actually evaluated to be equivalent to: `$this->b = new b;`, and then `return $this->b;`.

So to recap, the call-time evaluation of your getter will look like this:

```
function __get($v)
{
    $this->b = new b;
    return $this->b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

$b is actually instantiated because the property $b is undefined for $a and when calling $a->$b ... it calls the magic method __get with parameter $v = $b, so the line

```
$this->$b = new $b;
```

is executed.

Answer (score 1):

The __get method is a magic method.  Whenever you try to access a property of an object in PHP, and that property is not defined, the __get method is called with the property name as the argument.

So, in this case you have:

```
$a->b
```

b is not a member of $a yet, so __get is called with b as the argument.  Then this gets run:

```
function __get($v) {
     $this->$v = new $v;
     return $this->$v;
 }
```

Substituting b for $v, so you get:

```
$this->b = new b;
```

That makes $a->b a new instance of b, which you then call the say member function on.

Answer (score 1):

It is instantiated here: `$this->$v = new $v;`

A breakdown:

Create the A object
    $a = new a();

```
$b = $a->b;
```

This dynamically calls `a::__get`

```
function __get($v)
{
   $this->$v = new $v;
   return $this->$v;
}
```

This returns a `b` object so you're effectively doing:

```
$b->say('hello world');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look up magic functionality in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). The logic within `__get()` is creating and returning a new instance of `b`